# About Theorem 6.12(c) in "Principles of Mathematical Analysis 3rd Edition" by Walter Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question

I am reading "Principles of Mathematical Analysis 3rd Edition" by Walter Rudin.

The author wrote the following theorem on p.128.

> Theorem 6.12(c):
> If $f\in\mathscr{R}(\alpha)$ on $[a,b]$ and if $a<c<b$, then $f\in\mathscr{R}(\alpha)$ on $[a,c]$ and on $[c,b]$, and $$\int_{a}^{c}f d\alpha+\int_{c}^{b}f d\alpha=\int_{a}^{b}f d\alpha.$$

But the author didn't write the following theorem in this book:

> If $a<c<b$ and if $f\in\mathscr{R}(\alpha)$ on $[a,c]$ and If $f\in\mathscr{R}(\alpha)$ on $[c,b]$, then $f\in\mathscr{R}(\alpha)$ on $[a,b]$, and $$\int_{a}^{c}f d\alpha+\int_{c}^{b}f d\alpha=\int_{a}^{b}f d\alpha.$$

Why?
I think the above theorem is also important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is important but it follows from the definition of Riemann's integral and the fact that if a sequence (say $a_n$) has a limit (say $a$) and a sequence (say $b_n$) has a limit (say $b$) then the sequence $a_n + b_n$ also converges and its limit is $a+b$. I am sure this is formulated somewhere as a theorem in Rudin's book.